# How to AJAXify ASP:Wizard Control

Tags: ajax, asp.net-3.5, aspwizard

Happy Friday All,

I have an ASP.net 2.0 website that I'm updating to .Net 3.5.  The site uses a master page and I've placed asp:UpdatePanel in it.

One of the pages has a 3-step wizard control that I'd like to "Ajaxify" in some way.  Are there better controls in the AJAX control toolkit that provide an improved user experience over the asp:Wizard control?

Please share with me your efforts to improve upon the asp:Wizard control.  Did you move to a different control?  Stay with asp:Wizard and add effects to it?

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of late, but I'll answer.  I used the Telerik RadAjaxManager control to ajaxify my Wizard control, and I regretted it because of performance issues.

If I were you, I'd pursue setting up divs and use JQuery to selectively show/hide them to emulate a wizard.